# numpy where with array of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

Why can't I find the location of a tuple in an array?  Afterall, the bottom expression prints `True`

```
foo = numpy.array([(5, 30), (5,), 5])
bar = numpy.where(foo==foo[0])
print(bar)
```

Prints `(array([], dtype=int64),)`

```
print((5,30)==foo[0])
```

Prints `True`

Comment: `foo` is a `dtype=object` array (different size tuples).  Many of the usual numeric array operations, including comparison, are not implemented for this dtype.  `foo` should be a list.

Comment: foo = numpy.array([(5, 30), (5,), 5]) ----> NOWADAYS ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because:

```
import numpy

foo = numpy.array([(5, 30), (5,), 5])
bar = numpy.where(foo==foo[0])
print(foo==foo[0])

False
```

That's why you're getting an empty array. A list comprehension alternative is `[v for v in foo if v == foo[0]]` will result in `[(5, 30)]`