# numpy.where with a 2d array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

I have a 2D numpy array of tuples like below:

```
a = np.array([[(2, 3), (np.inf, 10)],
              [(2, 2), (7, 8)]], dtype=object)
```

I used `b = np.min(a)` and got `b = (2, 2)`.

However, when I try to get the index of the minimal element with `np.where(a==b)` I get an empty index array.

So how to use `numpy.where` with an array of object?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy where with array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609871/numpy-where-with-array-of-tuples). That would be a matter of different types - `object` vs. `tuple`

Comment: I don't get your results: `print(b)` gives me `2` and `print(np.where(a==b))` gives me `(array([0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)`?

Comment: Alex, thanks for your answer.  So i will try with list element.

Comment: Hi Timus,
I forgot to mention how i created the array :
import numpy as np
a=np.empty((2,2),dtype=object)
a[0,0]=(2,3)
a[0,01=(np.inf,10)

Comment: Hi Timus,
I forgot to mention how i created the array :
import numpy as np
a=np.empty((2,2),dtype=object)
a[0,0]=(2,3)
a[0,1]=(np.inf,10)
a[1,0]=(2,2)
a[1,1]=(7,8)

I've tried to create a 2d array of tuple.  I'd like to find the index of the minimum element with numpy.where but as in the post pointed out by Alex, it's not supported. So we must use a list comprehension.